# Getting ride of the {

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    l.State, e.CorpID, e.LocID, tl.State AS 'Transferred From State',       
    e.TransferFromLocID AS 'Transferred From Location', 
    e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.SSN, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), e.CurrentBeginDate, 101) AS 'Start Date', 
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), e.BeginDate, 101) AS 'Begin Date', 
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), e.TermDate1, 101) AS 'Term Date', 
    (ISNULL(w.EligibleCode1, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(w.EligibleCode2, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(w.EligibleCode3, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(w.EligibleCode4, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(w.EligibleCode5, '')) AS 'Eligibility Code',   
    w.Disqualified, dcrs.StatusDescription AS 'DCR Status', 
    vt.TrackingCodes,      
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), w.DocRequestDate, 101) AS 'Doc Request Date',
    (CASE 
        WHEN w.RequestComplete = '0' 
          THEN  
            (CASE 
                WHEN w.EligibleCode1 IN ('I','A','G') 
                  THEN
                    (CASE 
                       WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '11' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '11') 
                         THEN '11'
                         ELSE '' 
                     END)
                WHEN w.EligibleCode1 IN ('B','J','Z') 
                  THEN
                    (CASE 
                        WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 NOT IN ('4','11') AND w.DocRecvd2 NOT IN('4','11')) 
                          THEN '4, 11' 
                        WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '4' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '4')   
                          THEN '4'
                        WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '11' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '11') 
                          THEN '11'
                        ELSE '' 
                     END)
                WHEN w.EligibleCode1 IN ('C') 
                  THEN
                    (CASE WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 NOT IN ('6','11') AND w.DocRecvd2 NOT IN('6','11')) THEN '6, 11' 
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '6' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '6') THEN '6'
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '11' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '11') THEN '11'
                    ELSE '' END)
                WHEN w.EligibleCode1 IN ('D','F') THEN
                    (CASE WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 NOT IN ('1','9') AND w.DocRecvd2 NOT IN('1','9')) THEN '1, 9' 
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '1' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '1') THEN '1'
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '9' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '9') THEN '9'
                    ELSE '' END)
                WHEN w.EligibleCode1 IN ('E') THEN
                    (CASE WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 NOT IN ('5','11') AND w.DocRecvd2 NOT IN('5','11')) THEN '5, 11' 
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '5' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '5') THEN '5'
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '11' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '11') THEN '11'
                    ELSE '' END)
                WHEN w.EligibleCode1 IN ('H') THEN
                    (CASE WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 NOT IN ('10','11') AND w.DocRecvd2 NOT IN('10','11')) THEN '10, 11' 
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '10' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '10') THEN '10'
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '11' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '11') THEN '11'
                    ELSE '' END)
                WHEN w.EligibleCode1 IN ('W','Y') THEN
                    (CASE WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 NOT IN ('4','11','13') AND w.DocRecvd2 NOT IN('4','11','13') AND w.DocRecvd3 NOT IN('4','11','13')) THEN '4, 11, 13' 
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 NOT IN ('4','11') AND w.DocRecvd2 NOT IN('4','11') AND w.DocRecvd3 NOT IN('4','11')) THEN '4, 11'
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 NOT IN ('4','13') AND w.DocRecvd2 NOT IN('4','13') AND w.DocRecvd3 NOT IN('4','13')) THEN '4, 13'
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 NOT IN ('11','13') AND w.DocRecvd2 NOT IN('11','13') AND w.DocRecvd3 NOT IN('11','13')) THEN '11, 13'
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '4' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '4' AND w.DocRecvd3 <> '4') THEN '4'
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '11' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '11' AND w.DocRecvd3 <> '11') THEN '11'
                    WHEN (w.DocRecvd1 <> '13' AND w.DocRecvd2 <> '13' AND w.DocRecvd3 <> '13') THEN '13'
                    ELSE '' END)
            ELSE '' END)    
        ELSE '' END) AS 'Docs Needed',
        (CAST(w.DocRecvd1 AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(w.DocRecvd2 AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(w.DocRecvd3 AS VARCHAR(5))) AS 'Docs Received'
FROM 
    Employee e
LEFT JOIN 
    Location l ON (l.CorpID = e.CorpID AND l.LocID = e.LocID)
LEFT JOIN 
    Location tl ON (tl.CorpID = e.CorpID AND tl.LocID = e.TransferFromLocID)
INNER JOIN 
    EmpWOTC w ON w.Wormnumber = e.Wormnumber
LEFT JOIN 
    EmpTrackingCode tc ON tc.WormNumber = e.Wormnumber
INNER JOIN 
    TrackCd t ON t.TrackingCodeID = tc.TrackingCodeID
INNER JOIN 
    vw_TrackingCodes vt ON vt.WormNumber = e.WormNumber
LEFT JOIN 
    EmpWOTCDCRAddress dcra ON dcra.Wormnumber = e.Wormnumber
INNER JOIN 
    EmpWOTCDCRStatus dcrs ON dcrs.StatusID = dcra.StatusID
WHERE 
    w.CertRecvdDate IS NULL
    AND (e.BeginDate BETWEEN '1/1/2010' AND GETDATE())
    AND w.ICFIssueDate IS NOT NULL
    AND w.eligible = 1
    AND vt.TrackingCodes Like '%HDF%'
    AND vt.TrackingCodes NOT Like '%^%'
    AND vt.TrackingCodes NOT Like '%OSB%'
    AND vt.TrackingCodes NOT Like '%N%'
    AND vt.TrackingCodes NOT Like '%S%'
    AND w.Disqualified = 0
ORDER BY 
    l.State, e.SSN
```

I have this code but the output for the trackingcodes column comes out with {xx}{yy} and so on how to get the same answers without having those { } and a space in between them? I'm bring this data into Excel for more manipulation and running more code on that one, but basically I need to be able to perform a state search for the results which i have. Then I want to search for different tracking code base on those states and with those { I cannot get Excel to find them. When I remove them and then separate them it works just fine.

Comment: Is that `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY`? Using [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for dates is strongly recommended.

Comment: @tadman: in this case it's both.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath In this arbitrary case, obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need to do is remove the brackets, you could use `REPLACE()`:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(vt.TrackingCodes,'}{',' '),'{',''),'}','') AS TrackingCodes
```

Used 3 `REPLACE()` instead of 2 so that the only space occurs between sets.